# Error is in expression '{!submit}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page : Class.Formtesting.submit:

Tags: apex

I am trying to submit the form, But it is giving error

```
    Error is in expression '{!submit}' in component <apex:commandButton> 
in page paconsentformtestingpage: Class.PAConsentFormtesting.submit: line 135, column 1
```

VF page:

```
    <apex:page controller="PAConsentFormtesting" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



   <!---<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size:A4 portrait;
        border: 2px solid black;    
    }
    </style>
    </head>--->

    <head>

     <style>
      div.three
      {
        margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;
        text-align:left;
        border:0px solid black;
        height:40px;
        padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
        float:left;
        visibility:hidden;
      }
    </style>  

    </head>



            <body onload ="ck();">


             <apex:form id="f">

             <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(isUser)}">
               <p style="margin-left:20px;font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">You don't have Permission to access this form.....</p>
             </apex:outputPanel>


             <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isUser}">

             <apex:actionFunction name="submitConsentForm" action="{!submit}"/>
             <!-- <apex:actionFunction name="upload" action="{!upload}"/> -->
             <div style="margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;"> 

               <div style="background-color:black">
              <apex:image value="{!$Resource.Deloitte_New_Black_Logo}" width="250" height="50"/><br/>
                </div>
              <h4 style="font-size:16px;">Promotion Agreement Acknowledgement</h4>

               <ul style="list-style:none;">
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;"><b>Name:</b> {!strinname}  </li>   
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;"><b>Personnel ID:</b> {!stringsapid }</li>   
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;"><b> {!legalEntity} </b></li>      
               </ul>

              <p style="font-size:14px;">To complete your acknowledgement, review Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California) and paragraphs 3 and 16 of the agreement and then complete the following:</p>
                <ul>
                 <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;"> 
                   If you have no Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements and wish to sign electronically please complete OPTION 1 in its entirety and submit.  
                 </li>
                 <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                 If you have Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements, or choose not to sign electronically, please complete OPTION 2. <br/>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p style="padding-left:20px;font-size:15px;"><i><b>Note:</b> The terms Pre-existing Creations, Pre-existing Agreements or Arrangements, Proceedings, or other italicized terms herein are defined in Exhibit A of your agreement.</i></p>

              <br/>

               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                  <th style="border:4px solid black;background-color:#87ceeb;height:35px;text-align:center;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;">
                    <h3 Style="font-size:16px;">OPTION 1 – ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE</h3><br/>
                  </th>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                  <td style="border:4px solid black;">

                  <p style="font-size:14px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;I understand that checking the below box constitutes my consent to use electronic means for my signature on this form and any attachments.</p>



                   <ul style="display:block;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;width:40px;line-height:40px;height:40px;text-align:center;">
                       <!---<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onchange="ck(this)"/>--->
                       <apex:inputCheckbox id="c1" value="{!opt1}" onchange="ck(this)"/>
                       <apex:image value="{!$Resource.checkedicon}" width="30px" height="30px" rendered="{!isCheck}"/>
                     </li>
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height:20px;width:560px;font-weight:bold;"> 
                      I am consenting to use electronic means to sign this form and any attachments.
                     </li>
                   </ul>

                     <br/><br/><br/>

                    <p style="padding-left:20px;font-size:15px;">Please complete the following steps in order to complete this process:</p>
                     <ul>
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                        Review the agreement attached to the email you received
                      </li>
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                     If you accept and agree to comply with the terms of the agreement, check the below box <b>"I have read and understand the agreement and agree to comply with its terms."</b>
                      </li>

                     </ul>

                     <ul style="display:block;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                       <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;width:40px;line-height:40px;height:40px;text-align:center;">
                        <!---<input type="checkbox" id="c2" onchange="ck(this)"/>&nbsp;--->
                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="c2" value="{!opt2}" onchange="ck(this)"/>&nbsp;
                        <apex:image value="{!$Resource.checkedicon}" width="30px" height="30px" rendered="{!isCheck}"/>
                       </li>
                       <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height:20px;width:560px;font-weight:bold;"> 
                         I have read and understand the agreement and agree to comply with its terms.
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                     <br/> <br/> <br/>

                     <ul>

                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">If you <b>do not have</b> any <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements:</i>
                      <ul>
                           <li style="list-style:circle;line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">Check the below box<b> "I have read and understand Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California) and paragraphs 3 and 16 of the agreement, and have no<i> Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements."</i></b></li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                      <!--<li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                       If you <b>do not have</b> any <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements:</i>
                       <ul>
                         <li style="list-style:circle;line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                           Place an “X” in the below box “I have read and understand Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California) <br/>and paragraphs 3 and 16 of the agreement, and have no Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements”
                         </li>
                       </ul>
                      </li>-->
                     </ul>

                       <ul style="display:block;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                         <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;width:40px;line-height:80px;height:80px;text-align:center;">
                          <!---<input type="checkbox" id="c3" onchange="ck(this.value)"/>&nbsp;-->
                          <apex:inputCheckbox id="c3" value="{!opt3}" onchange="ck(this)"/>
                          <apex:image value="{!$Resource.checkedicon}" width="40px" height="40px" rendered="{!isCheck}"/>
                        </li>
                        <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height:20px;width:560px;font-weight:bold;"> 
                          I have read and understand Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California) and paragraphs 3 and 16 of the agreement,
                          and have <i>no Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements.</i>
                       </li>
                     </ul>

                     <ul style="margin-top:80px;">
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">Click on the submit button to acknowledge your agreement.</li>
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">Retain the agreement and correspondence for your records.</li>
                     </ul>  



                  </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>
              <br/>

               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <th style="border:4px solid black;background-color:#87ceeb;text-align:center;padding:4px 4px 4px 4px;">
                    <h3 style="font-size:16px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">OPTION 2 – HANDWRITTEN SIGNATURE</h3><br/>

                  </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="border:4px solid black;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;width:500px;">

                 <apex:outputPanel id="d1" >

                   <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    If you prefer a handwritten signature, print the attached promotion agreement. Sign the promotion agreement if you accept and agree to comply with its terms.<br/>
                   </p>

                   <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    Review Exhibit B <b>(Exhibit B1 in California)</b> and paragraphs 3 and 16 of the promotion agreement.<br/>
                   </p>

                   <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    If you <b>have</b> <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements, </i> check the below box <b> "I have <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements"</i></b> and see the instructions following OPTION 2 <br/>
                   <br/>
                   </p>


                  <ul style="display:block;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;width:40px;line-height:40px;height:40px;text-align:center;">
                       <!---<input type="checkbox" id="c4" onchange="ck(this)"/>&nbsp;-->
                       <apex:inputCheckbox id="c4" value="{!opt4}" onchange="ck(this);ck2();"/>
                       <apex:image value="{!$Resource.checkedicon}" width="30px" height="30px" rendered="{!isCheck2}"/>
                     </li>
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height:20px;width:500px;font-weight:bold;"> 
                       I have <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangement.</i>
                     </li>
                   </ul>

                  <br/><br/><br/>
                  </apex:outputPanel>


                  <apex:outputPanel id="d2">
                   <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    If you <b>do not have</b> any <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements,</i> check the below box <b> "I do not have</b><i> Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements."</i>.  Within Exhibit B <b>(Exhibit B1 in California)</b> of your agreement, place an “X” on the line next to <i>“No Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements,”</i> sign, date and print your name where indicated on Exhibit B <b>(Exhibit B1 in California)</b>.
                    <br/>
                   </p>

                   <ul style="display:block;list-style:none;font-size:13px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;padding-right:3px;width:40px;line-height:40px;height:40px;text-align:center;">
                       <!---<input type="checkbox" id="c4" onchange="ck(this)"/>&nbsp;-->
                       <apex:inputCheckbox id="c5" value="{!opt5}" onchange="ck(this);ck3();"/>
                       <apex:image value="{!$Resource.checkedicon}" width="30px" height="30px" rendered="{!isCheck3}"/>
                     </li>
                     <li style="float:left;border:1px solid black;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;line-height:20px;width:500px;font-weight:bold;"> 
                        I do not have <i>Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangement.</i>
                     </li>
                   </ul><br/><br/><br/>


                    <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    Once you have selected one of the boxes above, scan the promotion agreement, and any Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements, and upload all materials here.<br/>
                   </p>

                   <p style="line-height:22px;font-size:15px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                    <b>Note: You may upload one file only. If you have multiple documents to submit, please include all of them in a single .zip file to be uploaded.</b><br/>
                   </p>





                   </apex:outputPanel>

                   <ul>
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">Click on the submit button to acknowledge your agreement.</li>
                      <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">Retain the agreement and correspondence for your records.</li>
                     </ul>  

                     <p style="float:left;margin-top:10px;font-weight:bold;margin-left:50px;" id="n"></p>

                    <!--  <apex:inputHidden value="{!name}" id="na"/> -->
                    <br/>
                    <div id="inp" style="margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;margin-top:30px;text-align:left;border:1px solid black;height:70px;padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;text-align:center;visibility:hidden;">
                     <!--- <p>
                        Once you have selected one of the boxes above, scan the promotion agreement, and any Pre-existing Creations, Agreements or Arrangements, and upload all materials here.
                      </p>--->

                      <br/>


                     <!-- <input type="file" id="input-file"/>&nbsp; -->

                       <apex:inputFile value="{!body}" fileName="{!name}" />
                     <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Upload" onclick="validateUpload();return false;" style="background:blue;width:100px;height:30px;color:white;"/> -->

                    </div>

                  </td>
                </tr>   
               </table>



              <p style="line-height:28px;font-size:15px;" align="left">
              <u>Additional instructions related to Option 2:</u><br/>
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;If you have any information relevant to the exhibits listed below that you wish to provide,<br/>
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California):<i> Pre-existing Creations; Pre-Existing Agreements or Arrangements</i><br/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Exhibit C: <i>Proceedings</i><br/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Exhibit D: Exceptions to Post-<i>Employment</i> Restrictions re: Clients</b>
              </p>

              <p style="font-size:15px;">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;you must proceed as follows: <br/>   
               <ul>
                 <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                  <b>If you are listing any <i>Pre-Existing Creations or Pre-Existing Agreements or Arrangements,</i> </b> you will need an <i>Authorized Signatory</i> to accept and agree to your listings and to sign Exhibit B (Exhibit B1 in California).
                </li>
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                 <b>If you are listing any <i>Proceedings</i></b>, you will need to disclose them in writing and sign Exhibit C. 
                </li>
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                 <b>If you are requesting any exceptions to the post-<i>Employment</i> restriction re:</b> <b>clients,</b> you will need an <i>Authorized Signatory</i> to accept and agree to your listings and to sign Exhibit D.
                </li>
                <li style="line-height:28px;font-size:14px;">
                 Reply to the US ELE Promotion Agreements mailbox if you need assistance with the process for submitting any information relevant to Exhibits B (Exhibit B1 in California), C or D.
                </li>
               </ul>
             </p>
               <p style="font-size:15px;">
               Upon completion of these additional steps, please return to OPTION 2 and complete the remaining steps.
              </p>
            </div>

              <center>
               <apex:commandButton value="SUBMIT" action="{!submit}" style="width:250px;background:blue;height:40px;font-size:14px;color:white;visibility:hidden;" id="cb" styleClass="one">
                  <apex:param name="opt1" value="opt1" assignTo="{!option}"/>
               </apex:commandButton>
              </center>

               <p id="stmsg">{!response}</p> 

             </apex:outputPanel>  
               <script type="text/javascript">
                    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
                </script>
                <script src="/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function uploadFile()
                    {
                        var input = document.getElementById("input-file");
                        var filesToUpload = input.files;

                        var st;

                        if(filesToUpload.length<=0){

                          alert('No file Choosen');
                        }
                        else{

                        for(var i = 0, f; f = filesToUpload[i]; i++)
                        {
                            var reader = new FileReader();

                            // Keep a reference to the File in the FileReader so it can be accessed in callbacks
                            reader.file = f;

                            reader.onload = function(e)
                            {
                                var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");


                                 var fileName, fileExtension;

                                fileName =input.files.item(0).name; 

                                fileExtension = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));

                                att.Name ='Signed Promotion Agreement.'+fileExtension;

                                console.log('Attachment Name:'+att.Name);

                                var filename=this.file.name;
                                att.ContentType = this.file.type;
                                att.ParentId ='{!pid}';

                                var binary = "";
                                var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                                var length = bytes.byteLength;

                                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
                                {
                                    binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                                }

                                att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(binary)).toString();

                                sforce.connection.create([att],
                                {
                                    onSuccess : function(result, source)
                                    {
                                        if (result[0].getBoolean("success"))
                                        {

                                            var fna='AttachedFile: '+filename;
                                            sforce.apex.execute("PAConsentForm","setName",{fname:fna});

                                            document.getElementById('n').innerHTML='AttachedFile: '+filename;
                                            console.log("new attachment created with id " + result[0].id);

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    onFailure : function(error, source)
                                    {
                                        console.log("an error has occurred " + error);
                                    }
                                });
                            };

                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
                        }
                      }



                    }
                </script>


              <script>
             function ck()
             {
              var v1=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c1}').checked;

              var v2=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c2}').checked;

              var v3=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c3}').checked;

              var v4=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c4}').checked;

              var v5=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c5}').checked;



                 if(v1==true&&v2==true&&v3==true)
                 {
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.cb}').style.visibility='visible'; 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.cb}').style.visibility='hidden'; 
                  document.getElementById('inp').style.visibility='hidden';  
                 }

                 if((v1==true||v2==true||v3==true)&&(v4==true||v5==true))
                 {
                   document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.cb}').style.visibility='hidden'; 
                   document.getElementById('inp').style.visibility='hidden';  
                 }
                 else
                   if(v4==true)
                   {
                     document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.cb}').style.visibility='visible';
                     document.getElementById('inp').style.visibility='visible';   
                   }
                   else
                    if(v5==true)
                    {
                      document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.cb}').style.visibility='visible'; 
                      document.getElementById('inp').style.visibility='visible';   
                    }
              }

              function ck2()
              {
                document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c5}').checked=false;
              }

              function ck3()
              {
               document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c4}').checked=false;
              }

              function uploadCheck()
              {
                var v4=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c4}').checked;

                var v5=document.getElementById('{!$Component.f.c5}').checked;

                var name=document.getElementById('n').innerHTML;

                var val=document.getElementById('stmsg').innerHTML;



                if(val.length>3){

                  alert('Already Submitted');
                }
               else{
               if(v4==true||v5==true)
               {
                 var input=document.getElementById('input-file');

                  var filesToUpload = input.files;




                  if(name!='')
                  {
                      uploadFile();
                      submitConsentForm();

                  }
                  else
                  if(filesToUpload.length<=0)
                  {
                     alert('No file choosen');
                  } 

               }
               else{


                    submitConsentForm();
                  }
               }

              }

              function validateUpload(){

                 var input=document.getElementById('input-file');

                 var filesToUpload = input.files;




                 if(filesToUpload.length<=0)
                 {
                     alert('No file choosen');
                 }
                 else{


                        document.getElementById('n').innerHTML='Attached File: '+input.files.item(0).name;

                        document.getElementById('{!$component.f.na}').value='Attached File: '+input.files.item(0).name;

                      }
                }


</script>

  </apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
global class PAConsentForm {

        //public String renderAs { get; set; }

        public string strinname {get;set;}

        public string stringsapid {get;set;}

        public string legalEntity{get;set;}

        public ELE_Agreement__c pa{get;set;}

        public ELE_Agreement__c ea;

        public  attachment a{get;set;}

        public Blob body{get;set;}

        public  string name{get;set;}

        public string pid{get;set;}

        public Boolean opt1{get;set;}

        public Boolean opt2{get;set;}

        public Boolean opt3{get;set;}

        public Boolean opt4{get;set;}

        public Boolean opt5 { get; set; }

        public Boolean isCheck{get;set;}

        public Boolean isCheck2{get;set;}

        public Boolean isCheck3{get;set;}

        public Boolean isUser{get;set;}

        public List<Attachment> la;

        public string response{get;set;}

        public string opt;



        public PAConsentForm ()
        {

          pid=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

          User u=[Select id,accountID,ContactID,email from user where id=:userInfo.getUserId()];


          la=new List<attachment>();

         try
         {
          ea=[Select Acknowledgement_Date__c,email__c from ELE_Agreement__c where ID=:pid LIMIT 1];

           if(ea.email__c==u.email){

             isUser=true;

           }

           if(ea.Acknowledgement_Date__c!=null){

              response='submitted';
           }


           pa=[Select id,Legal_Name_of_the_Employee__c,Legal_Entity__c,SAP_ID__c,contact__r.name from ELE_Agreement__c where id=:pid];

           opt=ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('option');
           strinname = pa.contact__r.name;
           stringsapid = pa.SAP_ID__c ;
           legalEntity=pa.Legal_Entity__c;



            isCheck=false;
            isCheck2=false;
            isCheck3=false;

          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {

          }

            /*if(opt=='opt1')
            {
              isCheck=true;
              isCheck2=false;

              pa.Consent_1__c=true;

              pa.Consent_2__c=true;

              pa.Consent_3__c=true;

            }
            if(opt=='opt2')
            {
              isCheck2=true;
              isCheck=false;

              name=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('para');

              pa.Consent_4__c=true;

            }*/


        }

         public pageReference p2;

         //public string statusMsg{get;set;}

        public pageReference submit()
        {
           System.debug('###  submit'+name+' end');

            if(ea.Acknowledgement_Date__c==Null)
            {

            a=new attachment();

            pageReference p=new pageReference('/apex/PA_ConsentFormPdf');

            p.getParameters().put('id',pid);

            if(opt1==true&&opt2==true&&opt3==true)
            { 

            p.getParameters().put('option','opt1');

            pa.Consent_1__c=true;

            pa.Consent_2__c=true;

            pa.Consent_3__c=true;

            isCheck2=false;
            ischeck3=false;
            isCheck=true;
             p2=page.PAThankYou;

            }

            //pageReference p=new pageReference('/apex/PA_ConsentFormPdf');

            //p.getParameters().put('id',pid);

            if(opt4==true)
            {

              p.getParameters().put('option','opt2');

              p.getParameters().put('para',name);

              pa.Consent_4__c=true;

              isCheck2=true;
              isCheck3=false;
              isCheck=false;
              upload();
              //insert la;

              p2=page.PAThankYou;  
            }

            if(opt5==true)
            {

              p.getParameters().put('option','opt3');

              p.getParameters().put('para',name);

              pa.Consent_5__c=true;

              isCheck2=false;
              isCheck3=true;

              isCheck=false;
              upload();
              //insert la;

              p2=page.PAThankYou;
            }

            Blob con=p.getContentAsPdf();

            a.parentID=pid;

            a.name='Consent Form.pdf';

            a.body=con;

            insert a;


            pa.Candidate_Response__c=true;

            pa.Out_of_Office__c=false;

            pa.Agreement_Status__c='Signed';

            pa.Acknowledgement_Date__c=Date.Today();

            //pa.Email_Received_Date__c=Date.Today();

            update pa;

                if(la.size()>0)
                {
                    System.debug('### Attaching Uploads');
                    insert la;

                }

            //renderAs='pdf';
           }
           else
           {

             p2=null;
           }

          return p2;

        }

        public PageReference upload()
        {

             System.debug('### Attaching called'+name+' end');
          //name='Attached File:'+' '+name;
          try 
          {
           if(name!=null)
           {
               string ext='';
               if(name.indexOf('.')!=-1)
               {
                    ext = name.substring(name.indexOf('.'), name.length());
               }

               System.debug('### ext'+ext);
               Attachment atemp=new attachment();
               atemp.parentID=pid;
               atemp.body=body;
               atemp.name='Signed Promotion Agreement'+ext;
               la.add(atemp); 
           }

          }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Exception_Log__c errLog=WCT_ExceptionUtility.logException('PAConsentForm', 'PA ConsentForm', e.getMessage()+'   in:'+e.getStackTraceString()+ '   due to:'+e.getCause());



              }
              return null;
        }
```

}

line no 135 is

```
 if(ea.Acknowledgement_Date__c==null)
```

Comment: What is the actual error? NullPointerException?

Comment: Attempt to de-reference null object

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide an ID parameter to the page, so the record is null. You would have caught this sooner if you didn't have a try-catch block in your constructor. Make sure you have a valid ID on your page, and the user can access it:

```
/apex/mypage?id=aXXXX00000XXXXX
```

If you meant to be able to use this page without an ID, to create a new record, you should make sure you initialize "ea" in your constructor:

```
if(pid == null) {
  ea = new ELE_Agreement__c();
} else {
  ea = [select ... from ELE_Agreement__c where id = :pid];
}
```

Comment: I have passed Id at URL. Still same error

Comment: I have passed Id at URL. Still same error. Error is “Attempt to de-reference null object”

Comment: @Frank you'll need to remove the try-catch in your constructor. I'm guessing you have the wrong Id.